# adding variable to itself with postfix increment different in Java/c# than in C

Tags: java, c, postfix-notation

In Java and C# if I do this:

```
int i=1;
int j= i++ + i;
```

j is 3, i.e. it translates to 1+2 and increments i before the addition.

However, in C j is 2, i.e. it translates to 1+1 then increments i.

What is the internal mechanism in C and Java/C# that causes this difference in what an expression is?

(the same goes for post-fix. Java/C# become 4 and C becomes 3.)

thanks.

Btw, initially I assumed it would be what the C answer was and so was confused by the Java/C# result.

Comment: It's undefined in C, well-defined in Java and C# (by language standards, not some implementation mechanisms)

Comment: In Java and C#, you have left-to-right evaluation. So `int j = i++ + i;` first (after evaluating the location to store, `j`) evaluates `i++`, giving 1 and storing 2 in `i`, then evaluates `i` giving 2, adds, giving 3, stores in `j`.

Comment: Cheers. I just assumed it would be the whole expression, i.e. 'i++ + i' before  it incremented i

Comment: How can `int j= i++ + i;` be undefined behavior in C? There are two side effects in the expression: j is modified, i is modified. The same variable is not modified twice between sequence points. It may be _unspecified_ behavior, as in the code depends on order of evaluation, but that's something completely different from UB.

Comment: @Neil I'm assuming you meant to write `int i=1;` on the first row?

Comment: C, Java, and C# are different languages. You cannot assume code means the same just because it looks the same. You have to learn and apply the rules for each language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Java and C# which specify precisely when the side effects would take place, C prohibits the use of an expression with side effects before the next [*sequence point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). Not only does your expression produce a different result in C, but it is also undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, I assumed C had the correct answer and Java/C# must be doing something odd ;)

Comment: @Neil Nope, in C your program is wrong, i.e. there is no right or wrong behavior for that expression. There are compilers that do it one way, as well as compilers that do it the other way. The plus `+` is not a sequence point, so the result is undefined.

Comment: _What_ exactly is undefined behavior in this code? _Accessing_ a variable twice without sequence points in between is perfectly fine, otherwise `x + x` would be undefined behavior. C only states UB if a variable is modified twice without a sequence point in between.

Comment: @Lundin Value computation (in this case, the second reference of `i`) without a sequence point counts as UB as well: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. "

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Aha, I didn't know that. Still, how is this expression unsequenced? It is unspecified whether i++ or i will be evaluated first, but they will both evaluate to the same result. The actual ++ happens after all operand evaluations. Should we read the standard as "if an expression with the same variable appearing twice without sequence points in between, depends on order of evaluation, it is not unspecified but undefined behavior"?

Comment: After reading John Bode's answer, I'm guessing that it is the actual ++ operation that is unsequenced, since it happens after the evaluation of i++, but before the next sequence point. Where exactly that is sequenced in relation to the addition isn't clear, hence UB. Shoot me if got it wrong :)

Comment: @Lundin My reading of this is slightly different: the standard calls for the side effect to be unsequenced relative to the other read, without saying which of the two expressions needs to be evaluated first. I think it omits the order on purpose, because both `i++, then i` and `i, then i++` evaluation orders are allowed. The behavior is truly undefined in only one of these two cases, but since the other case is a possibility, the standard has no choice but declare an otherwise OK expression an UB.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the mechanism is a finely-tuned celebration of compiler-writing skills affectionally known as [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), or "UB".

In other words, nobody can provide an answer for C, since the code is known in advance to trigger undefined behavior. Anything could happen, there's no "right" or "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

From the [2011 draft of the C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.5 Expressions
>
> ...
>
>
> 2 If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>  subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
>   effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
>
> 3 The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.<sup>85)</sup> Except as specified
>    later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced.<sup>86)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```
>
> 85) The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same
> as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first. Thus, for example, the
> expressions allowed as the operands of the binary + operator (6.5.6) are those expressions defined in
> 6.5.1 through 6.5.6. The exceptions are cast expressions (6.5.4) as operands of unary operators
> (6.5.3), and an operand contained between any of the following pairs of operators: grouping
> parentheses () (6.5.1), subscripting brackets [] (6.5.2.1), function-call parentheses () (6.5.2.2), and
> the conditional operator ? : (6.5.15).
> Within each major subclause, the operators have the same precedence. Left- or right-associativity is
> indicated in each subclause by the syntax for the expressions discussed therein.
> 86) In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and
> indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently in
> different evaluations.

The order in which the side effect of `i++` is applied relative to the larger expression `i++ + i` is *unspecified*; the two operations are unsequenced relative to each other.  If the side effect is applied immediately after `i++` is evaluated, then you'll get the result of 1 + 2.  If the side effect is deferred until after the addition, you'll get the result of 1 + 1.

The older version of the standard was a bit clearer; an object may have its value modified *at most once* by the evaluation of an expression between sequence points, and the prior value of the expression is used only to determine the new value to be stored.

The behavior is left *undefined* so that the compiler isn't required to detect these issues and issue a diagnostic (`i++ + i` is easy enough to catch, but there are far more subtle variations of this problem that are a lot harder to detect).  Either result is "correct" as far as the language definition is concerned.

Answer (score -3):

In C, post increment/decrement will be executed after the current operation is done.
in this example, i++ + i; i will be incremented after the addition is done.